# Give the Volume of a Sound a Character is currently making

Tags: audio, character, unreal-5

I'm looking to have a sound file drive the location of a bone or morph target, to create a basic form of lip syncing. Specifically, I'm looking for help getting the volume of the sound file as a float.

An example of what I mean can be seen in Half Life 1. The scientist has an audio file, and the volume of the audio causes the mouth to open depending on how loud the volume is.

https://youtu.be/JoV9o6b91Sc?t=466

https://i.makeagif.com/media/3-19-2021/JmU6Gx.gif

This seems very simple but I havn't really found anything on doing this in Unreal.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Getting the current volume level of a sound file, or moving a bone or morph target to a provided value? These are two separate tasks and should probably be two separate questions.

Comment: The first, I really just need a float from the volume and I can do the rest.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Audio Synesthesia](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WorkingWithAudio/Synesthesia/) plugin?

Comment: Thank you @Adam, this looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By use of 'Audio Synesthesia' I managed to do this. I followed [This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1W_fWg-Cb9U&ab_channel=KyleGeske) to do it, plugging the value into a Morph target that moves the mouth.

Thanks to @Adam to the guidence

Comment: This answer would he even better if it briefly outlined the steps you needed to follow. That way, even if the tutorial goes offline in the future, the key information is preserved for future readers.